# Sharepoint - How to fix web-part date filter from vertical to horizontal

Tags: sharepoint, layout, filter, format

I added three web part date filters (including the apply filter button).

I want to go from

[image]

to this

[image]

i tried changing the zone orientation to horizontal but there is just too much space in between the fields and the button.. they are like this

[ FIELD ]-------------------------[FIELD]-----------------------------[BUTTON]

instead of

[FIELD] [FIELD] [BUTTON]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the developer dashboard (f12), & check for default margin & padding. You can override the height & width by giving required dimensions. Please ensure to use `!important` to override any dynamic calculations for placeholders.

If you are using the filters on only one page, you can add script/content editor to embed the style otherwise page-layout or master-page level styling can be embedded.

Comment: Not sure which ID or class to apply that too.. there are so many, and on top of that they are long generated numbers which probably change every time the page loads..

Comment: Look for classes ex. container zones. IDs will change!